# jquery alerts on checked boxes in gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi I have following code that selects or de selects check boxes in a gridview which works fine.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkAll']").click(function () {
               if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                   $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']").attr('checked', this.checked);
               else
                   $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']").attr('checked', false);
           });
       });
```

My next step is to use .each class and iterate through each check box and display alert message.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#mainForm').click(function () {
               $("<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkAll']:checked").each(function () {
                   alert("checked box");
               });
           });
```

The above code does not work. Any suggestions how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second bit of code the selector is missing the `#`

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#mainForm').click(function () {
           $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkAll']:checked").each(function () {
               alert("checked box");
           });
       });
```